# Render HTML file content and assign it to an Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is what my initial js looks like

```
// template.js
file: {
  template : '<div><h2>Template</h2><p>My paragraph</p></div>';
}
```

But I need to create this as a separate html file.

```
<!-- template.html -->
<div>
  <h2>Template</h2>
  <p>My paragraph</p>
</div>
```

Now I need to import and assign it to an object (template) of a script. Any ideas how to do this?

```
// template.js
file: {
  template : 'Content Here';
}
```

Comment: Load the file with Ajax?

Comment: you can use [.get()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)

Comment: Could you post an attempt? you have to try to learn asking is not enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to get it via AJAX. This will be a pseudo-promise (see: [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and [`$.get()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)) that is resolved with the contents of the file:

```
$.get(templateUrl).then(...)
```

So a good example would be:

```
// assuming `file` is inside `options`
if (options.file.template == null && options.file.templateUrl != null) {
  $.get(options.file.templateUrl).then(function(html) {
    options.file.template = html
    // continue doing stuff with the newly received html...
  });
}
```

Notice how I separated them into `template` and `templateUrl`, but you don't have to do that.

Note: if you try to use to use the result outside the promise's callback, you will probably get `undefined` when you try to access it (unless some time has passed) so you might need to organize your code to accommodate to that.